# lua screenshot from windows

Tags: windows, lua, screenshot

I'm writing a lua program that I would like to link with my computer's screenshot function (I'm running Windows). Does anyone know how to take a screenshot if a condition is met in my program? I haven't been able to find any help in my searches. I think I could make use of Lua's 'os.execute ([command])' but I'm not sure how to reference Window's screenshot cmd from there. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: [May be helpful](http://superuser.com/a/943947/467273)

Comment: That may work. Do you know where to place the screenCapture.bat file so that cmd line recognizes it? Thanks.

Comment: simply use the full path of any folder of your choice. if you don't want to provide a path you have to add the containing folder to your PATH environment variable so Windows can find it

Comment: When I run the file in my cmd window, I get the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect." Do you think that may be a problem with the file itself or my computer's ability to run it? (Or my lack of debugging?) Thanks.

Comment: @dh21 - Try another answers of that SuperUser question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wxlua/wxwidgets or have access to a compiled binary, something like this may work:

```
require "wx"
local width, height = wx.wxDisplaySize()
local bitmap = wx.wxBitmap(width, height, -1)
local memDC = wx.wxMemoryDC()
memDC:SelectObject(bitmap)
memDC:Blit(0, 0, width, height, wx.wxScreenDC(), 0, 0)
memDC:SelectObject(wx.wxNullBitmap)
bitmap:SaveFile("screenshot.png", wx.wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

This should take a screenshot of the entire screen, but you can easily customize it to take a screenshot of a particular area of the screen.